# Disable the enter key

Tags: c

Would it be possible to prevent the user from pressing the enter key before typing their actual input in C programming? For example,

```
int num;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf ("%i", &num);
```

I would like to be able to disallow the user from pressing the enter key, moving the cursor down a line until a character has been typed. Would it be possible to accomplish this?

Comment: You want to ignore the input, not stop the user from pressing the button. (What are you going to do, overvolt the key and melt it in place?)

Comment: With platform-specific code, you can alter the terminal settings to disable character echo. Then, you control exactly what appears on the terminal. This doesn't prevent the character from hitting your program, but you can choose to not have it move the cursor down.

Comment: @user2357112 Don't give his project manager any ideas...